Server Error in '/' Application.An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request
My admin site is not working however my live site is working properly and also i checked the connection string also in both the application - CMS and My project. So below mention  is my error when i run my administrotor at my localhost:-
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source Error:
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace:
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Runtime.Tracing.PageInspectorHttpModule.OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e) +646
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +217
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +181
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +93
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.9232.0
I were expecting the solution of my problem .

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  There is zero context in how you're getting this stack trace.  You need to include more information.  If your admin site is not working, what is the difference between the admin site and the working live one?  Is this a code related issue or an IIS setup issue?  I can't tell.  What are the inputs?  What did you do to get this traceback?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
